# MYSQL split out records except latest from multiple duplicates

Tags: mysql, split, timestamp, duplicates

I've been looking for hours to find this and while there are a lot of variations I can't quite seem to close the loop on my specific requirement....every time I think I've got it it slips away from me :)

so here it is;

I've imported a bunch of records into a table with ultimately unique rows but with some duplicate data in certain columns.
<strike>I want to split out the records into two tables - one table with DISTINCT or UNIQUE 'code' records that have the latest timestamp within their 'code' group, and one table with the rest of the records</strike>

[EDIT - Sincerest apologies, I have to rephrase as I don't think I articulated very clearly the first time - in fact I got it very wrong...sorry!]

I have multiple columns with unique ROWS only - (i.e. each column has duplicate data, but the combination of all columns in a specific row is unique - obviously excluding the primary key)

What I need is the row that contains the **latest timestamp** for a **code** within a specific **area_id**.
In the example below I've excluded the other columns as I view these three as key;

```
TABLE#1
        code    area_id   timestamp    
         1        2      2010-02-31 00:00:00
         2        2      2012-01-31 00:00:00
         2        2      2011-02-31 00:00:00
         1        5      2010-02-31 00:00:00
         2        5      2010-02-31 00:00:00
         1        2      2011-01-31 00:00:00
         1        5      2012-01-31 00:00:00
```

So the structure of the answer I'm trying to phrase is;

"For the combination of code **1** & area_id **2**, the latest timestamp is **2011-01-31 00:00:00"** - return that row.

Repeat for each combination of code and area_id.

so;

```
RESULT
        code    area_id   timestamp    
         1        2      2011-01-31 00:00:00
         2        2      2012-01-31 00:00:00
         1        5      2012-01-31 00:00:00
         2        5      2010-02-31 00:00:00
```

As I mentioned, there are quite a few other columns that need to come with the data when I split the rows out, but I think I can worry about that later - first step is to get the data in a result set without having mysql/workbench time out on me!

JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this is for table2

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE (code, timestamp) NOT IN (SELECT code, MAX(timestamp)
                                FROM Table1
                                GROUP BY code)
```

And then this to delete records from Table1:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE (code, timestamp) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT code, MAX(timestamp)
                                FROM yourtable
                                GROUP BY code) s)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea0c7/1) (I changed 31th of February to 28th, and 31th of April to 30th, I think it was a typo).

**Edit**

Since these queries are too slow to execute, you can try the JOIN version:

```
INSERT INTO Table2
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT code, MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp
                          FROM Table1
                          GROUP BY code) t2
     ON t1.code=t2.code and t1.timestamp=t2.max_timestamp
WHERE
  t2.code IS NULL;

DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT code, MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp
                           FROM Table1
                           GROUP BY code) t2
     ON t1.code=t2.code and t1.timestamp=t2.max_timestamp
WHERE
  t2.code IS NULL;
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbe1a/1).

Also, you can try adding one of more of the following indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON Table1 (code)
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON Table1 (timestamp)
CREATE INDEX idx3 ON Table1 (code,timestamp)
```

Comment: Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 600.532 sec...  ><  only around 500k rows in table...Trying again!

Comment: @user2213361 the first one or the second one? do you have any index? i could use a JOIN to make them a little more faster

Comment: The table I used here was just by way of explanation - I should have perhaps included my actual table, but there are quite a few columns...my Table1 has an AI PK column and as I copied the table structure to Table2 I'm guessing that trying to populate Table2 AI PK with values from Table1 AI PK might be causing some confusion to the DB...I've removed the Table2 PK column and specifically selected all columns from Table1 in the SELECT statement instead of using *....busy running again...

Comment: ...and lost connection to server after 600secs again :(

Comment: so I've tried a number of things to address both DB Operations timeouts (like removing columns) as well as query timeouts (my.cnf max_packet, DBMS timeout) which work - I've been able to strip out half the columns from the table, but the result is that the indexing has been running for 14hrs straight and is still "Running..."

Comment: Sincerest apologies - updated the question to more accurately reflect what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Finally got mysql responding (rebuild/reinstall), created indexes, adjusted join to latest query and it worked :)
INSERT INTO table2
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT code, area_id, MAX(timestamp) max_timestamp
                          FROM table1 tpo3
                          GROUP BY code, area_id) t2
     ON t1.code=t2.code and t1.area_id=t2.area_id and t1.timestamp=t2.max_timestamp